# Run bash script in Anaconda prompt

Tags: python-3.x, bash, anaconda

Perhaps this is me being an absolute newby with bash, but I can't find anywhere how to accomplish this. I have a python program which needs to run simultaneosly 3 scripts. So far, I just opened 3 spyder Ipython terminals and run each script on them.

I came across something called bash scripts which could easily run the 3 of them at the same time, so I decided to give it a go. I created a file like this in spyder

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Nov 30 14:56:08 2019

@author: Usuario
"""

#!/usr/bin/env bash

python Cornerbot.py &
python Betcornerbot.py &
python Cornerfixture.py &
```

and saved it as Initializer.sh

From what I gather, to open it on Windows in an anaconda prompt, I need to go to the folder, and tipe `sh Initializer.sh` but doing so Anaconda just tells me sh is not a command it recognizes

So, obviosly I'm doing something wrong. Am I creating the file in a wrong way (probably)? Is it hte way it is been called from anaconda prompt?
I would really appreciate any input as so far what I've looked on the Internet assummes I have a knowledge in bash I actually don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `python` is your language, why not something like this

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys
import subprocess

for cmd in ['Cornerbot.py', 'Betcornerbot.py', 'Cornerfixture.py']:
    subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, cmd], shell=False)
```

Also, regarding your question, perhaps you have to type `bash Initializer.sh` instead of `sh`.

Comment: How can I send in command line arguments along with the python script?

Comment: `subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, cmd, arg1, arg2], shell=False)`

Comment: It isn't ideal to execute Python scripts using a Python script which must be run in some un-explained shell. Better to use a solution like the answer below: execute your Python scripts from shell explicitly e.g. with bash. Then it's easier to control and manage the environment it's run in.

Comment: @Wassadamo that's opinion based

Answer (score 2):

The code to run your `Initializer.sh` is:

```
bash  Initializer.sh
```

Also, the characters of `&`, I think they are abundant. Since `&` is used for the `Command-line terminal`.

While your `Initializer.sh` is a bash script, which is a programming language like other Python, Java. It needn't `&` to combine code in different lines.

Comment: The `&` is POSIX shell syntax for [asynchronous execution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_03_02)